# ajax post script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just fiddled following script.
It's not working.

```
<SCRIPT> 

function kin() {
    var kobj = document.getElementById("k"); // input Object 
    var q = kobj.value; 

       $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      URL: "zips.php",
      data:q,
      success: function(res) {
            $("#result").append(res);
            console.log(res);
      }
   });

}

</SCRIPT> 

 <INPUT type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="k"><input type="submit" value="search" onClick="kin()" data-role="button">      
<DIV id="result"></DIV>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? How have you determined it's not working?

Comment: Excellent question: **I think it's not working**

Comment: Read this question because I thought it involved Ajax and Postscript...  Oooh, that sounds interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two errors in the code you posted. I commented old code, so you can easily notice changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<SCRIPT> 

function kin() {
    //var kobj = document.getElementById("k"); // input Object 
    //var q = kobj.value; 

    var q = $("#k").val();

       $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "zips.php",
      //data:q,
      data: "q="+q,
      success: function(res) {
            $("#result").append(res);
            console.log(res);
      }
   });

}

</SCRIPT> 

 <INPUT type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="k"><input type="submit" value="search" onClick="kin()" data-role="button">      
<DIV id="result"></DIV>
```

JQuery allows you to rewrite the code you posted like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT> 

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var q = $("#k").val();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "zips.php",
          data: "q="+ q,
          success: function(res) {
                $("#result").append(res);
                console.log(res);
        },
      });

    });       

});

</SCRIPT> 

 <INPUT type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="k"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="search" data-role="button">      
<DIV id="result"></DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
data:q,
```

try:

```
data:{"q":q},
```

Comment: How is that relevant? (the `return false` part)

Comment: Thanks @mgraph. I think the problem is not this script but zips.php.